# EF Core choose object with conditions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Can't get into one thing. I would be very grateful for help.

And so, to the problem: I have a list of `Foos` objects with inputs a and b that must meet two conditions, for example

```
db.Foos.Where(foo => foo.a == a && foo.b == b).ToList()
```

I need to calculate Delta(foo) on the `Foos` list, and select the object from the list where this delta is minimal.

Delta example:

```
foo => (a*2 + b) - (foo.a + foo.b)
```

Actually a question how can I select this object?

Comment: "how to me to select this object?" - Do you mean `db.Foos.Where(foo => foo.a == a && foo.b == b).Select(foo => (a*2 + b) - (foo.a + foo.b)).ToList()` ?

Comment: No, I meant that I need to choose the object that has the minimum Delta value.
Sorry for my bad English))
for example 
foo obj where delta min

Comment: You could order the result set by that and take the first value. `var fooWithSmallestDelta = db.Foos.Where(foo => foo.a == a && foo.b == b).OrderBy(foo => (a*2 + b) - (foo.a + foo.b)).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Can you show us more on how your data is structured, what the expected value, and the actual value of the response is please

Comment: I made my comment an answer. If that fixes it for you please mark it as such using the checkbox on the left side of the answer.

Comment: I have a mehod 
 async Task<Foos> IRepositoryQuery.FetchFoos(a,b) 
its exist Foos List with two conditions 
db.Foos.Where(foo => foo.a == a && foo.b == b).ToListAsync()
I want to get actual value Foo where 
Delta(foo)  foo => (a*2 + b) - (foo.a + foo.b)  is minimal value 
@simonprice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `foo` instance with the smallest delta value you can sort the filtered result set by the delta value so it is ordered with the smallest value first in the list and then take the first item from that result set.

```
var fooWithSmallestDelta = db.Foos
    .Where(foo => foo.a == a && foo.b == b)
    .OrderBy(foo => (a*2 + b) - (foo.a + foo.b))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```